# Foreach not firing, string not true array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a comma separated list of numbers from a post variable, which outputs e.g:

`123, 456, 789, 101, 112` // Number comma space

I then use the following code to process these IDs individually:

```
$id_string = $_POST['ids'];


$id_array = array_map('trim', explode(',', $id_string));

    foreach ($id_array as $value){
        $url = 'http://myserver.com';
        $data = array('a' => $value, 'reStock' => 'true');
        $get = array();

            foreach($data as $k => $v){
            $get[] = $k . '=' . urlencode($v);
            }

            $get = implode('&', $get);

            $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $get
            )
            );

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $mxsendstock = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    }
```

After testing all afternoon, I can't get the foreach to work - nothing happens. The only possible cause I can see is if I'm handling the comma-separated list correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might consider taking a look at the [http_build_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php) function

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it'll be very handy for me :) In terms of the actual process, the function seems to work without issue when using a real array, i.e. `$ids = 123,456,789;` So I'm trying to find out if I'm converting my string to an array properly. Thanks, J

Comment: "I can't get the foreach to work" is not helpful. People will need to spend time discovering *how* it does not work, which you already know. Please do tell.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Jon, as per the original post, how it doesn't work is: nothing happens. At all. Not a single Get request. Nothing. Thanks, J

Comment: A simple var_dump() of $id_array immediately before the foreach() should tell you if you're converting it to an array correctly

Comment: what does your trim function do?

Comment: I assume your using it to remove the spaces then since I don't see the code for it.

Comment: Why do you assume the problem is in the foreach? Without inspecting the contents of the array, how can you tell whether the foreach gets executed or not? Probably the problem is with the url your forming or the site your trying to reach. You should output some results within the loop (Or log them in some way) in order to have a clearer picture of what's wrong here.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by "Foreach not firing, string not true array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any problem using that like this?

```
<?php
  $id_string  = $_POST['ids'];
  $id_array   = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $id_string ) );

  foreach( $id_array as $value ) {
    $url  = 'http://myserver.com/';
    $data = array( 'a' => $value, 'reStock' => 'true' );
    $get  = http_build_query( $data );

    $mxsendstock  = file_get_contents( $url."?".$get );
    print( htmlspecialchars( $mxsendstock ) );
  }
?>
```

Comment: That's terrific, it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your answer.